# Spring boot 3.0.6 native image startup failing with 'entityManagerFactory': Instantiation of supplied bean failed

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-native

Spring boot 3.0.6
dependencies,
spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
spring-boot-starter-web

build with
mvn spring-boot:build-image -Pnative

source: https://github.com/askyora/native-service

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Instantiation of supplied bean failed
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.obtainFromSupplier(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1220) ~[com.example.demo.NativeServiceApplication:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1158) ~[com.example.demo.NativeServiceApplication:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[com.example.demo.NativeServiceApplication:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[com.example.demo.NativeServiceApplication:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[com.example.demo.NativeServiceApplication:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[com.example.demo.NativeServiceApplication:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[com.example.demo.NativeServiceApplication:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[com.example.demo.NativeServiceApplication:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1132) ~[com.example.demo.NativeServiceApplication:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:907) ~[com.example.demo.NativeServiceApplication:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[com.example.demo.NativeServiceApplication:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[com.example.demo.NativeServiceApplication:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[com.example.demo.NativeServiceApplication:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[com.example.demo.NativeServiceApplication:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[com.example.demo.NativeServiceApplication:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[com.example.demo.NativeServiceApplication:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[com.example.demo.NativeServiceApplication:3.0.6]
    at com.example.demo.NativeServiceApplication.main(NativeServiceApplication.java:10) ~[com.example.demo.NativeServiceApplication:na]
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No available JtaPlatform candidates amongst [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform, org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration.getNoJtaPlatformManager(HibernateJpaConfiguration.java:213) ~[com.example.demo.NativeServiceApplication:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration.configureJtaPlatform(HibernateJpaConfiguration.java:150) ~[com.example.demo.NativeServiceApplication:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration.customizeVendorProperties(HibernateJpaConfiguration.java:139) ~[com.example.demo.NativeServiceApplication:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.entityManagerFactory(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:132) ~[com.example.demo.NativeServiceApplication:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration__BeanDefinitions.lambda$getEntityManagerFactoryInstanceSupplier$3(JpaBaseConfiguration__BeanDefinitions.java:84) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingBiFunction.apply(ThrowingBiFunction.java:68) ~[com.example.demo.NativeServiceApplication:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingBiFunction.apply(ThrowingBiFunction.java:54) ~[com.example.demo.NativeServiceApplication:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanInstanceSupplier.lambda$get$2(BeanInstanceSupplier.java:204) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:58) ~[com.example.demo.NativeServiceApplication:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:46) ~[com.example.demo.NativeServiceApplication:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanInstanceSupplier.invokeBeanSupplier(BeanInstanceSupplier.java:216) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanInstanceSupplier.get(BeanInstanceSupplier.java:204) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.obtainInstanceFromSupplier(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:947) ~[com.example.demo.NativeServiceApplication:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.obtainFromSupplier(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[com.example.demo.NativeServiceApplication:6.0.8]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
```

https://github.com/askyora/native-service

Answer (score 2):

There is a [known problem](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/35423) with Spring Boot 3.0.6 and Hibernate 6.2. It should be fixed in Spring Boot 3.0.7, [to be released soon](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/milestone/295). The fix is in snapshot builds of 3.0.7 now.

You can manually downgrade Hibernate to 6.1 using the `hibernate.version` [property in your build](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix.dependency-versions.properties) temporarily if needed.

Comment: 3.0.7-SNAPSHOT working fine. 
However, My hibernate version is 6.1.7.Final. so, is it possible to fix this issue downgrading hibernate.version? 
`code
+ org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-core:jar:6.1.7.Final:compile (version managed from 6.1.7.Final) 
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:jar:3.1.0:compile (version managed from 3.0.0; scope not updated to compile)
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.transaction:jakarta.transaction-api:jar:2.0.1:compile (version managed from 2.0.0)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- jakarta.enterprise:jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api:jar:3.0.1:provided
`code

Comment: Wow - thks a lot for this answer! I have a Spring Boot Crud-App running (with security, jpa, hibernate, actuator,...) Upgrading from Spr.Boot 3.0.6 to 3.1.0 native image no longer started (same exception as above).
But just downgrading  Hibernate fixed it
In gradle.kotlin it is one line on global level:
`extra["hibernate.version"] = "6.1.7.Final"`